# Using a compass and straightedge, what is the shortest way to divide a line segment into $n$ equal parts?

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, geometric-construction

Sometimes I help my next door neighbor's daughter with her homework.  Today she had to trisect a line segment using a compass and straightedge.  Admittedly, I had to look this up on the internet, and I found this [helpful site](http://www41.homepage.villanova.edu/robert.styer/trisecting%20segment/).  There they claim that the fewest number of "steps" necessary to trisect the segment is $4$, where by one "step" we mean any stroke of the pencil, either with the compass or straightedge.

Immediately, this got me thinking about the length of other optimal constructions, which has led to the question of this post:

> What is a the minimum number of steps necessary to construct a segment of length $\frac{1}{n}$ given a segment of length $1$?

If $s(n)$ is the quantity in question, then this [other helpful site](http://www.mathopenref.com/constdividesegment.html) shows that $s(n)\le n+6$.  However, $s(2)=3$ and $s(3)=4$, so the bound is not sharp.  Also, we can see that $s(mn)\le s(m)+s(n)$ by creating a segment of length $\frac{1}{mn}$ from one of length $\frac{1}{n}$.

Finally, at the bottom of the first site, they hint at one method of construction, which involves drawing larger and larger circles.  Assuming their hint leads to an optimal construction (which would need to be proved), I believe that the first eight values of $s(n)$ starting with $n=1$ are:

$$0,3,4,5,5,5,5,6$$

This returns nothing on OEIS.  (The above numbers assume that the initial segment of length $1$ is marked off on a very long ray, else we'd have to add one for $n\ge3$ to lengthen the segment appropriately).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let starting segment is $AB$.
As one can see from first link, starting condition is "segment-on-the-line".
Anyway one can add $1$ line at the start to get this starting condition.

Consider **odd** $n$.

Let coordinates of starting points are: $A(-1,0)$, $B(0,0)$.

If point $C$ has coordinates $C(n,0)$, then (see **Figure 1**) coordinates of other points are:
$D\left(\dfrac{1}{2n},\dfrac{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}{2n}\right)$;
$\qquad$
$E(1,0)$;
$\qquad$
$P\left(-1+\dfrac{1}{n},0\right)$.

**Figure 1**:
[image: Figure 1]

Consider **even** $n$.

Let coordinates of starting points are: $A(0,0)$, $B(1,0)$.

If point $C$ has coordinates $C\left(\dfrac{n}{2},0\right)$, then (see **Figure 2**) coordinates of other points are:
$D\left(\dfrac{1}{n},\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n}\right)$;
$\qquad$
$E\left(\dfrac{1}{n},-\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n}\right)$;
$\qquad$
$P\left(\dfrac{1}{n},0\right)$.

**Figure 2**:
[image: Figure 2]

---

**Main idea**: For given $m$ to draw point $C(m,0)$ as fast as possible.

As I checked (up to $m=2048$), it is possible to draw point $C(m,0)$, applying

$$
1+\lfloor \log_2 m \rfloor
$$

steps, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is floor rounding function.

According to described construction, upper bound of (total) steps is
$$
3+\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor, \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is odd} ;
$$
$$
2+\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor, \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is even}.
$$

Upper bounds of steps (starting with $n=1$) are:
$$
0; ~~ 3, 4; ~~  4, 5, 4, 5; ~~ 5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6; ~~ 6,7,6,7, ...
$$

---

Examples:

$n=11$: build point $C(11,0)$ and follow figure 1 (total $6$ steps).

[image: 11-6]

$n=12$: build point $C(6,0)$ and follow figure 2 (total $5$ steps).

[image]

Comment: This is really great.  Thank you.  Now to show this construction is optimal, which seems pretty hard.

Comment: An excellent answer!

Comment: The exact value of steps (computer exhaustive search to get) are: $0; ~~ 3,4; ~~  4,5,4,5; ~~ 5,5,5,6,5,5,5,5; ~~ 5,5,5,6,6, ...$. E.g. $s(13)=5$: Given two points $A(0,0)$, $B(1,0)$. **1.** Draw c1(A, B) (take A as the center of the circle, B as a point on the circle to make a circle c1), intersecting line AB at C; **2.** Draw c2(B, A), intersecting line AB at D, and intersecting c1 at E,F; **3.** Draw c3(C, B), intersecting line AB at G; **4.** Draw line EG, intersecting c2 at H; **5.** Draw c4(H, D), intersecting line AB at $X(\dfrac{1}{13},0)$.

Answer (score 1):

A possibly simpler method to divide a given line into n segments is to draw a second line of any length above and parallel to the given line such that the start of that 2nd line is perpendicular to the start of the first line. Mark out the number of random but equal length segments desired on the 2nd line and then draw concentric circles starting at the start of the 2nd line. Construct an upright line perpendicular to the end of the first line so as to intersect the last circle drawn. Draw a radial line from the origin of the circles to that intersection point. Then drop lines perpendicular to the given line from the intersection of the radial line with the constructed circle diameters. You will have divided it up into n equal lengths.
Here is a drawing of the trisection of a line with some of the construction points hidden to avoid confusion. The blue line is the given line and the red line is the radial line drawn to meet the perpendicular upright from the end of the given line.[Trisection of Given Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZJEz.jpg)

Comment: Not an answer. The OP wants the construction with the fewest steps, not a "simple" one. If you want to help on this site, read the question carefully before you answer. You're not likely to contribute much to an old question that already has an accepted answer.

Comment: I think you'll find that my description is shorter and needed only one illustration to cover the steps needed to create a line divided into n equal lengths. Not sure what the problem may be with it as it is a) simple and b) brief. It can be done with little knowledge of geometry and it's terminology. Apologies if it offends your sensibilities.

Comment: The OP wants to minimize the number of actual construction steps (number of times you find an intersection of two lines or a line and a circle). The simplicity or the number of pictures doesn't matter in this question, though of course it affects the aesthetics of the proof. Not my sensibilities - you have answered a different question than the one asked.

Comment: I hoped to provide a method less complicated than what the "correct" answer provided. Looks like back to the drawing board to tally the marks needed for my simple, and easily understood, method to qualify for the shortest number of steps. Hopefully the step by step description of the "correct" answer can be followed to help the neighbor's daughter as well, something that might be of use given the context of the question. I'll concede that what I offered may not have been as direct an answer as was sought after, but thought it might still be of some help/use for the neighbor's daughter.

Comment: The neighbor's daughter is now 10 years older than when she came to her father with this question, so is probably no longer interested. But do tally the number of steps in your construction and see if it improves on the one in the accepted answer.

Comment: OK, I finally did the full construction and find that it takes 25 marks total to trisect the given line, including drawing the given line at the start of the process.  My previous illustration showed the most salient steps to the trisection as it left out the construction of the various perpendiculars (4 total) which took three marks each.
I simply hope that this may be of use to someone looking for a solution to the division of a line into n equal segments without requiring an advanced knowledge of Geometry.

Comment: +1 for the work you did. For more positive feedback answer some open questions.