# Constructing of sequences with steps already "existing" in sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

Sequence $\{a_k\}$ is built according to next rule:
$$
a_0=0;\\
a_1=1;\\
\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ~ \exists i,j ~ (0\leqslant i<j\leqslant n),\mbox{ so that } a_{n+1}-a_{n} = a_j-a_i.
$$

**Conjecture:**

for any $v\in\left[2^n+1,~ 2^{n+1}\right]$ there exists (described above) sequence, that $a_{n+2} = v$.

**Examples:**

$v=10 (n=3)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,8,10,...$;

$v=12 (n=3)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,8,12,...$;

$v=13 (n=3)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,7,13,...$ (any sequence $0,1,2,4,8,x,...$ is wrong);

$v=25 (n=4)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,7,13,25,...$;

$v=49 (n=5)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,7,14,28,49,...$;

$v=105 (n=6)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,8,15,30,60,105,...$;

$v=233 (n=7)$: appropriate sequence $0,1,2,4,8,16,30,59,117,233,...$;

**Question:** How to prove this conjecture? 
(or show counterexample: unreachable $v$ for $n+2$ steps).

Comment: Just curiosity: Where does this come from?

Comment: @vonbrand, when I answered to this Question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712918/using-a-compass-and-straightedge-what-is-the-shortest-way-to-divide-a-line-segm/714752#714752 , a new question appeared: How many steps are necessary to draw segment with length $v$, if segment with length $1$ is given on the line. Here $a_n$ are "coordinates" of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our approach is inductive, that is we assume we have already made sequences of appropriate lengths for all the intervals up to $[2^{n-1}+1,2^n]$ and want to extend these by appending one term to get the sequences for $[2^n+1,2^{n+1}].$

Let $2^n+1 \le v \le 2^{n+1}$ and consider the cases where $v$ is even or odd. First if $v=2k$ is even then we have $2^{n-1}+1 \le k \le 2^n$ so that we can select a sequence making $k$ in the right number of steps, and append $v=2k$ to it, since $2k-k=k$ and any sequence making $k$ has the difference $k=k-0$ in it.

On the other hand suppose $v=2k+1$ so that $2^{n-1} \le k \le 2^n-1$ (where the subtraction of $1$ here is valid since $v$ is odd and hence $v<2^{n+1}.$) Adding $1$ to these terms gives
$$2^{n-1}+1 \le k+1 \le 2^n.$$
We can now make a sequence for $k+1$ of appropriate length, and we may append $v$ to it, since $v-(k+1)=k$ and any sequence for $k+1$ contains $1$ and hence also the difference $(k+1)-1=k.$

Comment: @oleg567 I had a lot of fun working this out, and had several unfruitful attempts before figuring out the right approach was to break down the cases to even vs odds, and use previously constructed sequences to "bootstrap".